# ruby on rails syntax loop error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please can someone tell me what the problem is with this line of code. I am getting this error.

```
SyntaxError in OrdersController#new

C:/***/orders_controller.rb:55: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
                    @order.orderdesc => {i => @cart.line_items[i]}
                                       ^
```

This is the line of code

```
@cart.line_items.length.times do |i|
     @order.orderdesc => {i => @cart.line_items[i]}
end
```

orderdesc is a serializable column in the table and I think I am correctly allowing an array to be added to and stored depending on the size of line_items

Thanks

Comment: If it's an array why aren't you adding the map to an array? => is a hash rocket, not an assignment.

Comment: baihu: You have background in what languages? I'm curious, why you thought it was correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to add all `@cart.line_items` to `@order.orderdesc` then you're doing it wrong. Here's an improvement:

```
@cart.line_items.each do |item|
  @order.orderdesc << item
end
```

Or simpler:

```
@order.orderdesc += @cart.line_items
```

If you get `undefined method for nil:NilClass` then it means that your `orderdesc` is `nil`. You have to initialize to empty array.

```
@order.orderdesc ||= []
@order.orderdesc += @cart.line_items
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. orderdesc does act like an array. I read that the way to do this was by making it serializable. For some reason though when I tried both methods it didn't work. I tried various other things as well but I feel pretty stupid.

For the top one I get undefined method << for nil:NilClass
and the bottom one I get undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (when I loop around it)

I am using rails 3. My background is not from rails and I am learning as I go.

Comment: This hasn't worked so it looks like I'll make a new model and do it that way